# Is this simple threaded program multithreaded?

Tags: java, multithreading, scala

I wrote this program to sort 3 million random doubles but its taking a long time to sort. I was expecting roughly 7-15 minutes but I'm timing it now and its already been 30 min.

Note: Running on a MacBook Pro with I9 processor

I tried to use futures to no avail

https://pastebin.com/BB66Zce9

```
import scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer
import scala.concurrent.Future

object Day10 extends App {

  class SortThread(_name: String, _list: ListBuffer[Double]) extends Thread {
    val name = _name
    val list = _list
    var timeStart: java.time.LocalTime = null
    var timeFinish: java.time.LocalTime = null
    var minutesElapsed: Long = 0
    var secondsElapsed: Long = 0

    override def run(): Unit = {
      sort()
    }

    private def sort(): Unit = {
      println(s"starting $name")
      var temp: Double = 0.0
      timeStart = java.time.LocalTime.now()
      for (i <- 0 until list.length) {
        for (j <- 0 until list.length - 1) {
          if (list(j) > list(j + 1)) {
            temp = list(j)
            list(j) = list(j + 1)
            list(j + 1) = temp
          }
        }
        Thread.sleep(1000)
      }
      timeFinish = java.time.LocalTime.now()
      minutesElapsed = java.time.Duration.between(timeStart, timeFinish).toMinutes
      secondsElapsed = java.time.Duration.between(timeStart, timeFinish).toMillis

      println(s"Finished $name")
      println(s"Minutes Elapsed: $minutesElapsed")
      println(s"Milliseconds Elapsed: $secondsElapsed")

    }
  }


  var list1 = new ListBuffer[Double]()
  var list2 = new ListBuffer[Double]()
  var list3 = new ListBuffer[Double]()
  var list4 = new ListBuffer[Double]()


//  // TODO: TESTING WITH SIMPLE LIST ================================
//  var testList = new ListBuffer[Double]()
//  for (i <- 0 to 100) {
//    testList += scala.util.Random.nextInt(1000-0).toDouble
//  }
//
//  val thread1 = new SortThread("thread1", testList)
//  thread1.sort()
//  for (i <- thread1.list) {
//    println(i)
//  }
//  // ===============================================================


  for (i <- 1 to 750000) {
    val randomNumber = scala.util.Random.nextInt(1000-0).toDouble
    list1 += randomNumber
    list2 += randomNumber
    list3 += randomNumber
    list4 += randomNumber
  }
  println("Finished adding 750,000 elements to 4 lists")

  val threadA = new SortThread("threadA", list1)
  val threadB = new SortThread("threadB", list2)
  val threadC = new SortThread("threadC", list3)
  val threadD = new SortThread("threadD", list4)

  println("Now starting the sorting!...")

  threadA.start()
  threadB.start()
  threadC.start()
  threadD.start()
}
```

Im expecting it to be quicker. The teacher said it took him 8 min on his desktop at home. The actual output is at least 30 min.

Comment: Your teacher executed the same program? With the Thread.sleep(1000) too?

Comment: I do not understand the title "Is this simple threaded program multithreaded?" simple == 1; multi == various (more than 1) - and how this describes the question/problem...

Comment: list has 750_000 elements, sleeping just one second for each element gives us about 750_000 seconds, that is roughly 8 days (for one of four lists) (only valid for Java, I do not program {often} in Scala)

Comment: Also, ListBuffer in Scala have a `O(n)` performance for getting `n`th element, so that sorting will take a lot longer than expected. You should use Java Array or Scala ArrayBuffer instead.

Answer (score 1):

Everything looks fine for me except that I don’t understand why you have Thread.sleep(1000) in your for loop. Remove it and you should see improvement!